# Ng-class Conditional Syntax

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to conditionally apply a class to an element but I can't get the syntax correct

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
ng-class="{foo: bar === "true"}"
```

`bar` is a boolean value.

Also, the element already has a `class` attribute.  Will `foo` be appended to the list of classes?

Comment: You can also use javascript condtional operator there.. like as a?a:b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the double quote on your evaluation, because it's closing your ng-class attribute. You can use the single quote if you want to check a string.
In you're case, if bar is a boolean value, you don't have to use quotes at all :

```
ng-class="{foo: bar === true}"
```

which is equivalent to

```
ng-class="{foo: bar}"
```

In case of a string, use :

```
ng-class="{foo: bar === 'your_string'}"
```

If your element already has a class attribute, foo will be appended to the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-class="{'checkedClass': trueVariable}
```

Here is a post explaning the same http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/conditionally-apply-a-css-class-with-angularjs